# Xamarin : iOS Device logic board get damage

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Since we started developing App using Xamarin Studio, 4 device's logic board get damaged. i.e. auto restart the device, auto power off etc.

Earlier we developed using xCode and never face this kind of issue. Is this related to Xamarin Studio?

PS: This issue is only for iOS devices and not for Android.

Comment: Never had any issues. We have several iOS devices which all are working just fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Cheesebaron for confirmation. But not able to found the root cause of the issue. Even if any coding issue, the device should not get damaged as we are working on simple client-server communication app. Working on native iOS development 8+ years and not found this kind of issue. Since started working on Xamarin studio, in 6 months, 4 devices get damaged.

Comment: I've been working with Xamarin on iOS and Android for almost 7 years now without any devices being damaged. Must be a coincidence that your devices get "damaged".